# how to calculate any exponential of a number without using a calculator or without having to memorize for each number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I mean, when we talk about small exponentials, you can even intuitively know, for example 8² = 64, or 10² = 100, but it starts to get complicated when there is a larger number, how to calculate exponentials of large numbers without using a calculator or without needing to memorize the result?

Comment: Do you have in mind for the exponents to be large, or the bases, or both?

Comment: @Lubin both bases and exponents

Comment: Well, if you’re looking for something like $38409912^{207832}$, you’re going to get huge numbers very soon, and the final value will take a lot of digits just to write it down. Is this a problem you need to know the answer to, or are you just being curious?

Comment: @Lubin just curious, but it does not need to be that that huge, something like 42^55 would be already large to me and I would need a calculator

Comment: Log table..........

Comment: How do you "intuitively" know that $8^2=64$? Intuition isn't the same as memorization. $42^{55}$ is an $89$-digit number. What makes you think there's a way to find it without a calculator? $42^{55}=189981351074408073951701600114073766275751709344935895421845768145404585904922034352160768$ by https://oeis.org/A009986/b009986.txt

Comment: Direct multiplication by hand, perhaps? It will only take some time.